# Standard method to not show form labels in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Is there a standard way to not have fields label in a Yesod form? My form makes it obvious what's to go in the field and I don't need a label.
So far I've coded my own, by copying and modifying renderDivs:

```
renderDivsNoLabel aform fragment = do
    (res, views') <- aFormToForm aform
    let views = views' []
    let widget = [whamlet|
\#{fragment}
$forall view <- views
    <div :fvRequired view:.required :not $ fvRequired view:.optional>
        $maybe tt <- fvTooltip view
            <div .tooltip>#{tt}
        ^{fvInput view}
        $maybe err <- fvErrors view
            <div .errors>#{err}
 |]
return (res, widget)
```

Any easier way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "easier way" would be to include your version of the render function in yesod-form itself. Want to send a pull request?